ERROR: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «materias» - postgresql
Actualmnente me encuentro trabajando en la creación de unas tablas con postgreSQL y tengo el siguiente error al intentar generar una foreing key entre la tabla de profesores y materias:

ERROR: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas
en la tabla referida «materias»

Aquí os dejo las tablas y la creación de las foreing key que me encuentro realizando.
Profesores:
CREATE TABLE PROFESORES ( 
    ID_Profesor numeric NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Nombre text, 
    Apellido text, 
    Direccion text, 
    Telefono numeric, 
    Especialidad text 
)

Materias:
CREATE TABLE MATERIAS ( 
    ID_MATERIAS numeric NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Materia text, ID_BACHILLERATO numeric, 
    ID_PROFESOR numeric 
)

Creación de la foreing Key:
ALTER TABLE PROFESORES ADD 
CONSTRAINT PROFESORES_ID_Profesor_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Profesor) 
REFERENCES MATERIAS (ID_PROFESOR); 


Que horrible! ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Tu problema es muy simple de resolver, es un problema de lógica, la tabla a la que tienes que crear la foreing key, es la tabla la cual la va a contener, no la tabla que contiene la primary key, ejemplo en vez de:
ALTER TABLE PROFESORES ADD 
CONSTRAINT PROFESORES_ID_Profesor_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Profesor) 
REFERENCES MATERIAS (ID_PROFESOR)

Debería de ser
ALTER TABLE MATERIAS ADD 
CONSTRAINT PROFESORES_ID_Profesor_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Profesor) 
REFERENCES PROFESORES (ID_PROFESOR); 

Ya que, según la tabla que creaste, el que va a contener la referencia de la tabla profesores va a ser materias y no viceversa.
Debido a que la consulta que realizaste se encuentra mal formulada, me tomé la libertad de editarla para que sea entendible al público.
Recuerda que muchas de las preguntas que realices por acá, van a servir de referencia a personas que puedan estar pasando por lo mismo, de ahí la importancia de la eligibilidad.
Saludos.

muchisimas gracias, estoy empezando en este mundo y voy aprendiendo poco a poco. gracias por tu respuesta y te notificare si me funciono

@AlexisChusler si la respuesta te funciono no olvides marcarla como aceptada.
